# Salesforce Debug log shows statements even after Fatal Error statement

Tags: apex, debug-logs

I am perplexed by something i see in debug log, and this could be very stupid question.

We have a parentObject and ChildObject (its not mater detail... just lookup relation).

We perform some update on parentObject, it runs triggers/workflows etc on parentObject, but also causes some updates on ChildObject. We are getting CPU timeout limit and i was analyzing log to see where it went wrong.

Log goes like this

```
Bunch of statements related to workflow, triggers, validation rules on parentObject
Bunch of statements related to workflow, triggers, validation rules on ChildObject
17:58:34.295 (104985273236)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded
Some stack trace here
Bunch of statements related to workflow, triggers, validation rules on parentObject
Bunch of statements related to workflow, triggers, validation rules on ChildObject
18:00:25.182 (104985209761)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded
```

This threw me off. So when time out limit was first encountered, whole transaction should have stopped. I should see error about CPU time limit as the last line in the debug logs. However, after that error, debug log shows significant number of more statements, before showing CPU time limit error again.

Could someone explain to me how we can see more statements in log after fatal error

Comment: That would be some duplicate statement which debug log normally has at the time of exception scenarios, it will throw some expectation and then at the end it will again print the exception or error at the end of log.

Comment: perhaps you have async logic being run before the fatal error? iirc This could cause more logic to run later/beyond/after the original fatal transaction.